# Converting xml to xls. How to write the path to my file?

Tags: excel, xml, vba

**Task**: convert xml to xls

**Problem**: When I run the program, nothing happens.

**Question**: How to write the path to my file?

It looks like this: C:\Program Files\new

```vb
Sub XMLTOCSV()
Dim f, p, s

p = "C:\Program Files\new\"
f = Dir(p & "*.xml")
s = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While Len(f) > 0
    s = s + 1
    ConvertXMLtoXLS p & f, p & Replace(f, ".xml", "") & ".xls"
    f = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoXLS(xmlFile, xlsFile)
Dim xlAppAs, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
xlBook.SaveAs xlsFile, 6
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Not tried, do not quite understand how to do it. Could you suggest?

Comment: I do not quite understand why you are talking about creating a folder, because I already have it and it contains a script and an xml file that needs to be converted. Or do you mean I'm creating a file, not a folder? Also I do not understand for what to change a line "C:\Program Files\New folder 2" into "C:\temp\". The question corrected and slightly changed the path where the xml file is located C:\Program Files\new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub XMLtoXLSX()
    Dim sPath As String: sPath = "C:\Program Files\new\test.xml"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call ConvertXMLtoXLSX(sPath, Replace(sPath, ".xml", "") & ".xlsx")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ConvertXMLtoXLSX(xmlFile, xlsxFile)
    With Application.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlFile, 2)
        .SaveAs fileName:=xlsxFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```